# Displaying two unconnected tables in one table

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to display data from two unconnected tables in one table ?

the two tables

[image]

the relations between them

[image]

Comment: (Off) Cool EER diagram, what program used?

Comment: Yes, there is a way but you should try something before we help.

Comment: Since there are _relations_ between the tables, they are also _connected_. Two joins should then give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use an `UNION` query and get all data without any correlation

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE A
UNION
SELECT *
FROM TABLE B
```

or you can use `INNER JOIN` query and use the three tables with correlated data but this will cause your query to be slower

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B
ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN TABLE C
ON b.id = b.id
```

Comment: When i try

SELECT *
FROM TABLE Pies
UNION
SELECT *
FROM TABLE Zawodnik;

i get this error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE Pies UNION SELECT * FROM TABLE Zawodnik LIMIT 0, 200' at line 2

Comment: @robertbrodowicz remove `TABLE` word from your query so it will be `SELECT * FROM Pies UNION SELECT * FROM Zawodnik`

Comment: SELECT * FROM Pies UNION SELECT * FROM Zawodnik; Error: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns